# Can we use onclientclick in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
        return confirm('Hello!');
        //return true;
}
</script>
<form method="get">
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff2'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='Enter Text Here' />
<input type='button' OnClientClick="return changeText2()" value='Change Text'/>
</form>
```

Is this possible in PHP? I tried it but I get an error. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: you can do this using AJAX, some examples: http://bit.ly/LAGDFw http://bit.ly/MZmUOq http://bit.ly/KxNJuO

Comment: AJAX can do that. Pure PHP cant.

Comment: to trigger a Javascript function, its just `onclick`.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Explain further what it is you want to do AND add the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

PHP doesn't have as complicated a template engine as ASP.NET.

You can simply use the HTML `onclick` attribute directly. There is no need to use a differently named one on the client because there isn't a server side attribute with the same name getting in the way.

Best practise, however, is to write [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [bind your event handlers programatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).